# How to Combine text and numerical features in training sets for machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, feature-extraction

I am trying to create a supervised machine learning model to predict probability of a given URL that belongs to `benign` or `malicious` class, based on both numerical features and text features.

**Numerical Featurs** -

- Length of URL
- Length of primary domain
- Number of dots
- Contains IP etc.

**Text Features** -

- Name of registrar
- Name of registrant
- Country
- List of words in URL etc.

I have dataframe with required features, but I don't know what to do with text data. Can someone guide me in this?

Below is an sample dataframe that i have-

```
   url_length    length_domain    is_ip    registrar    registrants    tokens_in_url
0      50              18           0         a1            z1        [abc, def, ghi, jkl]
1      98              23           0         a2            z2        [mno, pqr, stu]
2      146             8            0         a3            z3        [vwx, yz]
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use OneHotEncoder for text features that is categorical data. For reference [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn-preprocessing-onehotencoder) @NileshShaikh

Comment: You may even analyse, how the features in the data are contributing to the target, might be with the help of http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html, of course you would be doing typical frequency distribution, correlation etc.,

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following demo:

Source DF:

```
In [113]: df
Out[113]:
    registrar   registrant   country
0  registrar1  registrant1  country1
1  registrar8  registrant2  country2
2  registrar1  registrant3  country1
3  registrar5  registrant4  country3
```

Encoding:

```
In [114]: from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

In [115]: str_cols = df.columns[df.dtypes.eq('object')]

In [116]: clfs = {c:LabelEncoder() for c in str_cols}

In [117]: for col, clf in clfs.items():
     ...:     df[col] = clfs[col].fit_transform(df[col])
     ...:

In [118]: df
Out[118]:
   registrar  registrant  country
0          0           0        0
1          2           1        1
2          0           2        0
3          1           3        2
```

Inverse transformation:

```
In [119]: clfs['country'].inverse_transform(df['country'])
Out[119]: array(['country1', 'country2', 'country1', 'country3'], dtype=object)
```

**UPDATE:**

> Is it possible to use TF-IDF (List of words in URL) with your given
>   answer?

```
In [86]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

In [87]: vect = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5, analyzer='word', stop_words='english')

In [88]: X = vect.fit_transform(df['tokens_in_url'].str.join(' '))

In [89]: X
Out[89]:
<3x9 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [90]: X.A
Out[90]:
array([[ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.57735027,  0.57735027,  0.57735027,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.70710678,  0.70710678]])


In [91]: vect.get_feature_names()
Out[91]: ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yz']

In [92]: tok = pd.SparseDataFrame(X, columns=vect.get_feature_names(), index=df.index, default_fill_value=0)

In [93]: tok
Out[93]:
   abc  def  ghi  jkl      mno      pqr      stu       vwx        yz
0  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.000000  0.000000
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.57735  0.57735  0.57735  0.000000  0.000000
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.707107  0.707107
```

Comment: Bit lost on this one mate. Is this really combining numerical and text inputs in the best way for machine learning?

Comment: @roganjosh, most probably not. This might be helpful if there are too many different values in different columns...

Comment: I think this one is a bit broad. Country could be used as a category but I think this boils down to model selection as much as data preparation.

Comment: @MaxU, Is it possible to use TF-IDF (List of words in URL) with your given answer?

Comment: @NileshShaikh, can you provide a small reproducible data set?

Comment: @MaxU Edited question with sample dataframe.

Comment: `registrar1` -> `0`, `registrar8` -> `2` Does this assume there is a numerical relationship (or distance relationship) between registrars? @MaxU

Answer (score 2):

**To combine text features and numerical features follow this:**

- For Text Features,  vectorize it using BoW,TFIDF,AvgW2V,TFIDFW2V any of these text feature vectorization techniques.
- For Numerical Features ,  use Normalisation or Column Standardization to scale the numerical data.
- If in case you also want to use Categorical Features, then use OneHotEncoding, LabelEncoding, ResponseCoding etc , to vectorise the Categorical Features.
- Use hstack to put all the features in one dataframe.
  eg. X_tr=hstack((vectorised_text_features...., standardised_numerical_features..., standardised_categorical_features...))
  And, your Train Data is ready. Now , modelling can be performed.